# create multiple array on new keys with check the same keys,

Tags: php, arrays

I want to combine 2 array to be multiple array on new keys with checked the same keys. This is on image original arrays where the suborderid key is the key that determines them

Array 1: (`$pso`)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [suborderid] => 127
            [orderid] => 120
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [suborderid] => 128
            [orderid] => 120
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [suborderid] => 129
            [orderid] => 120
        )

)
```

Array 2: (`$items`)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [suborderid] => 127
            [title] => Kue Nastar
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [suborderid] => 128
            [title] => Kue Lapis
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [suborderid] => 128
            [title] => Kue Bakar
        )

)
```

this is the result that I want

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [suborderid] => 127
            [orderid] => 120
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [suborderid] => 127
                    [title] => Kue Nastar
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [suborderid] => 128
            [orderid] => 120
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [suborderid] => 128
                    [title] => Kue Lapis
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [suborderid] => 128
                    [title] => Kue Bakar
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [suborderid] => 129
            [orderid] => 120
        )

)
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
foreach ($pso as $key => $i){
   foreach ($items as $row => $l){
        $pso[$key]['items'] = $items;   
   }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code as text in the according formatting, don't post images containing text

Comment: You should also share your original arrays

Comment: this my original arrays https://imgur.com/BhWwoBX

Comment: @ogebman https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: @ogebman I see you've been struggling with your edits, I helped you a bit

Answer (score 1):

```
$newPso = [];

foreach ($pso as $val) {
    $newPso[$val["suborderid"]] = $val;
}

foreach ($items as $item) {
    $newPso[$item["suborderid"]][] = $item;
}

$pso = array_values($newPso);

print_r($pso);
```

First I create a new array with the values of `$pso` array, and the keys of its suborderid.

Then I just iterate the `$items` array and add the values. `array_values` is to get rid of the new keys.

Demo: https://3v4l.org/QIgjW

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$newArr=$pso;
foreach ($pso as $key => $i){
   foreach ($items as $row => $l){
        if($i['suborderid']==$l['suborderid']){ 
        $newArr[$key]['items']=$l;
        }
   }
}
```